# How to test destroy failure in ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

everyone.

I'm gonna test an active record object destroy failure but I've problems creating a failure situation.

I have a **before_filter** method called '**require_user_payment_info**' which validates the *@payment_info* object before the **delete** method is called, so I can't create a 'bad' *@payment_info* object before the **delete** method is called.

Here's the **require_user_payment_info** method:

```
def require_user_payment_info 
  @payment_info = credit_card_model.slave.find_by_user_guid(user_guid)
  if !@payment_info || @payment_info.user_guid != user_guid
    redirect_to(:controller => 'store', :action => 'index') and return false
  else
    if((@payment_info.card_expires_year.to_i < Date.today.year) || 
        ((@payment_info.card_expires_month.to_i < Date.today.month) && (@payment_info.card_expires_year.to_i == Date.today.year)))        
      @payment_info.card_account_public = "" #clear this out so the user is forced to re-enter the credit card number
      @payment_info.valid?        
      flash.now[:error] = t('ui_flash_errors.card_expired_error')
    end
  end
end
```

And the actual **delete** method:

```
def delete
  # required to be called via a delete request
  redirect_to :action => 'edit' and return if !request.delete?
  if @payment_info.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Delete SUCCESSFUL"
    redirect_to :action => 'new'
  else
    flash[:error] = "Delete failed"
    redirect_to :action => 'edit'
  end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks to me that a lot of that logic from the before filter should be on the model itself as a before_destroy callback. I'm not sure what you want to test though but you can stub whatever you need to make the flow go where you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
def test_delete
    payment_info = Factory.create(:payment_info, :user_guid=>@user.guid, :card_expires_month=>'04', 
                                    :card_expires_year=>(Date.today.year+2).to_s, :cardholder_city=>"test city",
                                      :cardholder_state=>'NC', :cardholder_country=>'US', :cardholder_zip=>'27612')
    PaymentInfo.any_instance.stubs(:destroy).returns(false)

    delete(:delete, {}, @session)
    assert_response(:redirect)
    assert_equal false, assigns(:payment_info).blank?
    assert_redirected_to({:controller=>'account', :action=>'edit'})
    assert_equal flash[:error], "There was an error deleting your credit card information. Please try again."
end
```